# How do I make ttk progressbar saturate rather than flip over?

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

If I `.step()` a `ttk.ProgressBar` to beyond it maximum, it flips over:

```
import Tkinter as tkinter, ttk
tk=tkinter.Tk()
p=ttk.ProgressBar(tk)
p.pack()

p.step(34)
p.step(34)
p.step(34)
#p.cget('value') is now 2.0 instead of 100.0
```

Can I make it saturate (i.e. remain at 100%) instead in this case?

I know I can write something like:

```
if step>=p.cget('maximum')-p.cget('value'):
    p.configure(value=p.cget('maximum'))
else:
    p.step(step)
```

but this is very convoluted. I wonder if there's some built-in way 'cuz this looks like a very common use case. Already checked https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_progressbar.htm.

Comment: `mode='indeterminate'` should do it. *"The current value of the progress bar. In determinate mode, this represents the amount of work completed. In indeterminate mode, it is interpreted modulo -maximum; that is, the progress bar completes one “cycle” when the -value increases by -maximum. "*

Comment: @stovfl That's not what I understood from the docs, and an experiment confirms my suspicion. In `indeterminate` mode, the bar doesn't show progress but rather displays a strob of constant length that travels across the bar as you `step` it.

Comment: If you don't want to *strob*, the only way i'm aware is your `if step>=p.cget('maximum')...`.